# Покупка без сдачи

Tags: алгоритм, математика, арифметика

У нас есть N сумма в рублях и K количество всех монет, которые задаются пользователем. В распоряжении мы имеем 1, 2, 5 рублёвые монеты. Нужно вычислить O, D, P это количество каждой из монет разного номинала соответственно. То есть, N = 1*O + 2*D + 5*P и K = O + D + P. Как решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно, что N >= K и

```
N - K = D + 4P >= 0, D >= 0, P >= 0
```

Таких решений может быть много, так что дальше зависит от того, что вам нужно - одно решение или все. Или ищите одно решение (простейшее - P=0, D=N-K), или все. Собственно, все.

С потолка - 14 рублей, 10 монет. То самое простейшее - D = N-K = 4, P = 0, ну а O, соответственно, равно 6 монет. 6 по рублю, 4 по 2...